# nvd3 time H:M:S displaying incorrectly in axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to have the y2axis (on the right) display in hours, minutes and seconds but the values returned are incorrect.

I have the following unix timestamps in GMT:

```
        [1396303200000, 1481501473], //should display on y2axis as 00:11:13
        [1398895200000, 1467497437], //should display on y2axis as 00:10:37
        [1401573600000, 1481501521], //should display on y2axis as 00:12:01
        [1404165600000, 1481501493], //should display on y2axis as 00:11:33
        [1406844000000, 1481501630], //should display on y2axis as 00:13:50
        [1409522400000, 1481501668], //should display on y2axis as 00:14:28
        [1412114400000, 1481501615], //should display on y2axis as 00:13:35
        [1414796400000, 1481501605], //should display on y2axis as 00:13:25
        [1417388400000, 1481501557], //should display on y2axis as 00:12:37
        [1420066800000, 1481501567], //should display on y2axis as 00:12:47
        [1422745200000, 1481501501]  //should display on y2axis as 00:11:41
```

However, the values shown in nvd3 chart are not what i am expecting at all.. if i use epoch converter i do see the values i am expecting.

Have tried the following code but values are still displayed incorrect:

```
      chart.y2Axis
          .tickFormat(function(d) {
              return d3.time.format('%H:%M:%S')(new Date(d))
           });
```

Also tried:

```
return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d))
```

Can someone help explain what might be the issue?

Full working fiddle and code here http://jsfiddle.net/wrcjp79o/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the JavaScript `new Date(value)` constructor [expects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **value** - Integer value representing the **number of milliseconds** since 1
>   January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix
>   time stamp functions count in seconds).

You are giving it seconds, so multiple by 1000.

---

Second, you are using [d3.time.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format), which converts to local time.  You want to be using [d3.time.format.utc](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format_utc), if you always want UTC.

---

```
  chart.y2Axis
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d3.time.format.utc('%H:%M:%S')(new Date(d * 1000))              
       });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrcjp79o/3/).

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for helping. Following your suggestion the values when mousing over the black line seem to be correct but the y2axis on the right is unrepresentative of these values and unsorted

Comment: never mind. one of the values (second one in the series) was out of range causing the y2axis to go haywire.